# Unexpected effect using layout_marginBottom

Tags: android, layout

I want that when I set margin bottom, which makes part of the view go out of the screen / not visible, the whole layout shifts to the top, looking "the same" - means, not re-arranging the views inside.

But when I set the margin, in this simplified example case, to container shrinks or the layout inside moves to the bottom. Here are pictures to illustrate:

Before setting margin:

[image]

After setting 200dip margin bottom:

[image]

This is the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dip"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="200dip"
        >

        <View 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dip"
            android:background="#00ff00"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

What can I do to avoid this?

Comment: Could you post a drawing of what you want to achieve? I somehow do not get it.

Comment: Imagine the first screen is a piece of paper and I'm moving it up. That's what I try to achieve. But in the second screen you see that the layout inside is somehow rearranging.

Comment: I see. Please check out my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve that, try setting a negative top-margin top the view you want to move up.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dip"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="-200dip"
        >
```

Comment: marginTop works. The thing is, that in my "real" task marginTop didn't work properly and I had to switch to marginBottom. But since marginBottom is also not doing what I need, I'll try with marginTop again. Will come back later, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Perhaps you should post your real task to get the real answer you need ;-)

Comment: You mean, the initial problem. I would have to simplify it anyways, to make it more community friendly (and understandable). I just thought that marginBottom would be easier.